# In Electron, how to I call a JavaScript function when the index.html page loads?

Tags: javascript, electron, onload

I am using Electron to create a desktop app for my students. The purpose of the app is to help them prepare for a final examination. My app will have four learning modules. Each module will contain some original information about a certain topic, links to outside resources, and a quiz at the end of each module. It will also contain a link to a comprehensive test, to be taken only after completing all four modules. The app's main window will have five buttons: four buttons that link to a learning module and one button that links to the comprehensive test.

I would like to set up the app to track my students' progress through the modules and keep them from advancing to the next module until they have completed the one before it. For example, when a student opens the app for the first time, only the button for the first learning module will be enabled; all the other buttons will be disabled. When they pass the first module, only the button for the second learning module will be enabled; all the others will be disabled. And so on until they finish the comprehensive test.

What I need is: a way that each time the app is opened, a JavaScript function is called that will check the value of a "student progress variable" (possible values: 0 to 5) that is stored in the app. That value will determine which buttons are enabled and disabled when the app launches. The value will start at 0 and increase by 1 when a student completes a learning module.

My question is: in Electron, how do I call a JavaScript function when the index.html page loads? Code examples would be ideal. Thanks!

I have tried the onload event handler in the  tag with no luck. I have all of the button clicks working fine, I just can't figure out how to call a function when the index.html page loads.

Comment: What didn't work with the `onload` event? Isn't your function called?

Comment: Any chance to see a bit of code (could be for ex a simple typo...)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Here is a step-by-step account of what I want to do:

Step 1: index.html page loads and calls page_setup() function which is currently located at index.js.
Step 2: The first part of page_setup() function reads a JSON file, extracts the value of the progress field (possible values: 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5), and makes the value available in a variable for the 2nd part of the function.
Step 3: In the second part of the function, the value of the progress variable is used in a switch statement that determines how the buttons are displayed on the index.html page when the app launches. 
(cont'd)

Comment: EVERYTHING WORKS EXCEPT STEP 2. My problem is I am new to Electron; I don't know where in the directory structure to put the code that reads the JSON file (see "THE CODE THAT READS A JSON FILE:" below). 

When I pass the argument (the current value of progress field in the JSON file) into the function manually through <body onload="page_setup()">, the JavaScript that builds the page (see index.js below) is executed perfectly. Also, I can use the "THE CODE THAT READS A JSON FILE:" below independently to read the JSON file and display the value of the progress field in the console.
(cont'd)

Comment: INDEX.HTML
...
<body onload="page_setup([0 or 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5])">
  <div id="app_title">   
  <h1>Page Title</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="nav_btns">
    <button class="nav_btn" id="nav_btn1">Part 1</button>
    <button class="nav_btn" id="nav_btn2">Part 2</button>
    <button class="nav_btn" id="nav_btn3">Part 3</button>
    <button class="nav_btn" id="nav_btn4">Part 4</button>
  </div>
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
...
(cont'd)

Comment: INDEX.JS:

const nav_btn1 = document.getElementById("nav_btn1");
const nav_btn2 = document.getElementById("nav_btn2");
...

function page_setup(progress) {
switch(progress) {
case 0:
nav_btn1.disabled = false;
nav_btn2.disabled = true;
nav_btn2.style.opacity+=0.1;
nav_btn3.disabled = true;
nav_btn3.style.opacity+=0.1;
nav_btn4.disabled = true;
nav_btn4.style.opacity+=0.1;
nav_comp_test.disabled = true;
nav_comp_test.style.opacity+=0.1;
email_btn.disabled = true;
email_btn.style.opacity+=0.1;
break;
 ...
(cont'd)

Comment: THE CODE THAT READS A JSON FILE:

const fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('../db.json', 'utf-8', (err, jsonString) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  else {
    const data = JSON.parse(jsonString);
    console.log(data.progress);
  }
  });